# How to find if a filter is in the C# GlobalFilter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The ASP.Net MVC has the GlobalFilters.Filters.  I want to find if RequireHttpsAttribute is in the GlobalFilters.  I tried using GlobalFilters.Filters.Contains() but not knowing what type the RequiredHttpsAtrribute is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some LINQ:

```
var hasAttribute = GlobalFilters.Filters
    .Where(f => f.Instance is RequireHttpsAttribute)
    .Any();
```

Filters collection has a list of `System.Web.Mvc.Filter` elements. I filtered global filters collection for a filter, whose property `Instance` is of type `RequireHttpsAttribute`. Then I used [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out if there is at least one element in the collection.

The result `hasAttribute` is `true` if global filters collection has `RequireHttpsAttribute`, and `false` if not.